# Modifying Output from collections.Counter using Python

Tags: python, collections

I'm using the Python collections library to print out the most common character in a string and how many times it's repeated.

```
import collections
results = collections.Counter("this is fun")
listresults= results.most_common()
print listresults
```

this is what my result is :

```
[(' ', 2), ('i', 2), ('s', 2), ('f', 1), ('h', 1), ('n', 1), ('u', 1), ('t', 1)]
```

which is not what I want. I want something like

```
[(2,"i") (2, " "),...]
```

does anyone know how to produce the desired result?

Comment: You don't get that output for `collections.Counter("this is fun")`, do you?

Comment: no sorry the result was from something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> results = Counter("this is fun")
>>> r = results.most_common()
>>> what_i_want = [(y, x) for x, y in r]
>>> what_i_want
[(2, ' '), (2, 'i'), (2, 's'), (1, 'f'), (1, 'h'), (1, 'n'), (1, 'u'), (1, 't')]
```

I use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) because list comprehensions are often more efficient than using `for` clauses and take up far less space. Per your comment below, though, a `for` clause would look like what jamylak has suggested:

```
>>> what_i_want = []
>>> for x, y in r:
    what_i_want.append((y, x))
>>> what_i_want
[(2, ' '), (2, 'i'), (2, 's'), (1, 'f'), (1, 'h'), (1, 'n'), (1, 'u'), (1, 't')]
```

Comment: @TommyNgo `what_i_want = []` `for x, y in r: what_i_want.append((y,x))` List comprehension is much better though

Comment: @TommyNgo I updated the answer above with the for loop that jamylak indicated would be the equivalent of the list comprehension. As jamylak points out, though, a list comprehension would be the preferable way to create the list you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Another slightly less readable but still quite pythonic way:

```
import collections
results = collections.Counter("this is fun")
listresults= results.most_common()
print listresults
print zip(*reversed(zip(*listresults)))
```